# Disable everything but a hidden command for root access

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, root, hardening

linux security and root access question....

I'm setting up a server that has a validator node running on it for a substrate-based blockchain. I was trying to harden the security of my server. I set up ufw for all ports but those necessary for the node to operate. I set up 2FA, SSH with ed25519, and then I was spending time trying to figure out, if for some crazy reason someone got in... how could I stop someone from using `systemctl` or `poweroff` with `sudo` privilages. The goal is maximize uptime and remain in sync with the other nodes at all times.

Anyways, I started blocking `bash` commands for the user account that allows SSH and blocked SSH to `root`. Then I blocked a few more commands and thought, what if someone could find their way around this? So, I just started blocking too many things lol. Even though I disabled `sudo` for the user and blocked a number of commands the user could still use `systemctl` and `stop` the `service` for the node. Eventually I found this [guide](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/65822) on how to only allow a few commands for a user.

Update: I didn't properly remove the user from the sudo group. Afterwards they could still use `systemctl` but the system then allowed `systemctl` to pop up with an input for the root user password for authentication. Anyways, I just wanted something simple yet secure sooo....

I ended up removing all of the commands from the user and symlinked the su command and renamed it to a random command that only I know. All of the other commands done by the user respond with

`-rbash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: restricted: cannot specify /' in command names`

I took away `bash history` and `bash autocomplete/tab completion`. Now the only thing you can do is guess commands that will get you to the point where you still have to get past my `root` password. Is there a way for hackers to scan for available commands when there is only one available that is masked in this way?

Anyways, I'm saying all of this because I have always heard best security practices involve "disabling root". Sometimes I see it as just disable root SSH, which i already have done, but sometimes i read it like disable the root account. Some say disable the password and try to divvy it up with `sudo` privileges so it's more traceable to individual users.

In my case I need to preserve root access in some way but I basically hid everything within the root user. So, if anyone gets access to root it's over. But, it's behind 2FA, SSH, and an unknown command that just gets to where you can try a password to access root.

Am I thinking about this "disable root for security" all wrong and I should disable it completely or does it make sense what I've done so far?

Comment: Did you tried to prevent to use systemctl with sudoers file ?

Comment: @Jeriko, yes. I removed the user from the sudo group but there was still a prompt for the user password at that point when using systemctl, so it didn't even need sudo to use systemctl. After i realized that, instead of trying to figure out how to turn that off, i just thought id remove everything because of that guide i linked at the top of the article

Comment: It's not normal. 1) You don't need sudo right to check the status of a service, but you need it to stop the service 2) If the user does not have sudo right, the prompt for password don't shows up and a mail is sent to admins. Check again your sudoers file if any indirect entry allows your user to use systemctl with sudo (if your user belonging to another group that you gave this right for example). Modify it with the visudo command.

Comment: @Jeriko, you were right about sudo, I updated the question to reflect that. My original question though was really that i was trying to get peoples thoughts on making a random command that masked root access through the su command as the only command available to a user. Is this dangerous in any way or is there no harm and might even help with the security of my server?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [unix.se] or [sf].

Comment: @Kenster gotcha, thanks for the advice. I'll ask over there :).

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a SSH key and use this to login to a Linux server, instead of using a password, and do not share your private key.

The following link is a tutorial on how to create a SSH key one, https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-linux-unix/

You could also add user filtering with AllowUsers option in sshd_config file:

```
AllowUsers admin1@192.168.1.* admin2@192.168.1.* otherid1 otherid2

This allows admin1 and admin2 only from 192.168.1.* addresses and otherid1, otherid2 from anywhere.
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the good advice, people should try to never ssh using passwords. I already set up SSH with a password protected private key, disabled the ability to log in as root via SSH, added 2FA for SSH login, and disabled the possibility of logging in via SSH with a password. The password I'm talking about is the root access password after they get through all of that, but the command to be able to enter that password is random and hidden.